# Update Data and show it on UITableView iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, updates

I have a problem: update data in UITableView. I want to get new data from parseXML that response from Server and them update new data to UITableView. **I used beloww code, but it does not show new data on Table View. I wrote a `UpdateArray()` function to check new data and then I compare 2 Array,if diff `[Array count]` then I call `[tableview reloadData];`

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [temp count];

    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return 90;
    }



      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


            UILabel *FileNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 30)];
            FileNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
            FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
            FileNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            NSLog(@"Reseversed TEMP array %@",temp);
            FileNameLabel.text =[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [cell.contentView addSubview: FileNameLabel];
            [FileNameLabel release];

            UILabel *UploadTimeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 25)];

            UploadTimeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            UploadTimeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
            UploadTimeLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            UploadTimeLabel.text = [UploadTimeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [cell.contentView addSubview: UploadTimeLabel];
            [UploadTimeLabel release];

            UILabel *CompleteLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 12, 170, 25)];
            CompleteLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            CompleteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
            CompleteLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            CompleteLabel.text =@"Completed";
            CompleteLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
            [cell.contentView addSubview: CompleteLabel];
            [CompleteLabel release];
        }
            return cell;
    }
```

`UpdateArray()`

```
 -(void)updateArray{

   while (loop)
   {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:4.0];

        [FileCompletedArray removeAllObjects];
     // [temp removeAllObjects];
      ....
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:afRequest];

        [operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Success");
            NSString * parsexmlinput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response in Loop CompleteView: %@", parsexmlinput); 
           // dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self parseXMLFile:parsexmlinput];

            NSLog(@"File Completed array: %@", FileCompletedArray);
            NSLog(@"File Temp out array: %@", temp);
            NSLog(@"File Completed count: %lu",(unsigned long)[ FileCompletedArray count]);
            NSLog(@"File Temp out count: %lu", (unsigned long)[temp count]);
            // NSLog(@"State: %@", state);

            if([FileCompletedArray count ] != [temp count])
            {
                [temp removeAllObjects];
                temp= [FileCompletedArray mutableCopy];
                [_tableView reloadData];
            }
            else
            {
               NSLog(@"2 array equal");
            }
   //});
        }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                              NSLog(@"error: %@", error);

                                          }
         ];
        [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
   }
}
```

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: but the if-condition returns YES and enters the area and performs the reloadData? number of rows is called after this and the temp ary is correct? maybe set a breakpoint behind `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";`

Comment: WHen compare 2 array, it alway equals although server has new data. I wrong what step ?

Comment: thats an other issue you have to investigate. maybe check `[self parseXMLFile:parsexmlinput];`. also the content of `NSLog(@"File Completed array: %@", FileCompletedArray);
            NSLog(@"File Temp out array: %@", temp);` could be a good information. you only want to update if new rows are comming or also if data is updated? and you should look better for naming conventions, naming variables with great initial is a bad practice ;)

Comment: i only want update if data is updated

Answer (score 1):

I dont See that you call reloadData.

EDIT:

You must check that

1-Temp is having objects i mean that [temp count] is not returning zero.

2-The if condition that checks the two arrays is triggered . I mean that reload data is called.

3-You can make a breakpoint after cell.contetview addsubview and check what the cell contain now?

Comment: Actually i dont know why i dont see add comment under any question in stackoverflow i see only add comment on answers.

Answer (score 0):

before you call

```
[_tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[_tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

you have to call

```
[_tableView beginUpdates];
...
[_tableView endUpdates];
```

or call

```
[_tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I called [_tableView reloadData]; but it not reload tableView. Thanks. Do you have other suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh table view then try this line & check:

```
[[self mytableview] reloadData];
```

mytableview is obj of tableview you give here your tableview object.